# Targeting span within button tag on hover: How to change border color and pointer?

Tags: html, css, button, hover

I have some cards and want to change the properties `border-color` and `pointer-events` when a user hovers a `span` tag which is inside a `button` tag.

This is no problem if i use `a` tag, see First Card on the left:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JzzEvj

However, when using a PRG pattern with `form` and `button` changing the pointer event and the `border-bottom` color when hovering **does not work with Firefox**. (See Second Card on the right side)

Any ideas how to fix this in Firefox?

Desired outcome see Card on the left:

- The cursor should have `pointer` state when hovering the image
- The cursor should have `pointer` state when hovering the card heading
- The card heading's `border-bottom` color should change color when hovering the card heading

[image: https://i.imgur.com/fdWhZ7Y.jpg]

I spend a lot of time on this issue but only found this solution https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PLLWxJ which **is not exactly the same**, because

- the card heading's `border-bottom` color changes when hovering *any* part of the card.
- *all* parts of the card look clickable when hovering. The cursor state should only change to `pointer` when hovering the image or the card heading.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.product-cards-wrapper {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 64px 0;
}

.product-cards {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.product-card {
  border: 1px dotted #ccc;
  cursor: default;
  margin: 0 16px 32px;
  width: 250px;
  text-align: center;
}

.product-card-img-wrapper {
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 0;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.product-card-heading {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  color: #2bb3f0;
  display: inline;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.6;
  text-align: center;
  transition: border-color .2s;
}

.product-card-heading:hover {
  border-color: #2bb3f0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.product-card-label {
  background: #fee5ad;
  border-radius: 99px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .54);
  cursor: text;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-top: 4px;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}

.product-card>button {
  background: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.product-card-heading {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  color: #2bb3f0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: border-color .2s;
}

.product-card button .product-card-img-wrapper,
.product-card button .product-card-heading {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.product-card button .product-card-heading:hover {
  border-color: #2bb3f0;
}

.product-card-labels {
  display: block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<section class=product-cards-wrapper>
  <div class=product-cards>
    <a class=product-card href=#>
      <div class=product-card-img-wrapper>
        <img src=https://via.placeholder.com/160x150 alt="">
      </div>
      <div class=product-card-heading>First Card</div>
      <div class=product-card-labels><span class=product-card-label>Label</span></div>
    </a>
    <form class=product-card action=# method=post target=_blank>
      <button name=l value=123>
      <span class=product-card-img-wrapper>
       <img src=https://via.placeholder.com/120x150 alt="">
      </span>
      <span class=product-card-heading>Second Card</span>
      <span class=product-card-labels><span class=product-card-label>Label</span></span>
     </button>
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: As I can see your both cards are working same. What is the issue?

Comment: so you want the cursor pointer to target only the image  and the heading text?

Comment: I think I might be smelling the x-thousandths duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector here …?

Comment: "As I can see your both cards are working same. What is the issue?" --> I checked this again and found out that on Chrome it works fine. But with Firefox I have the problem like described.

Comment: "so you want the cursor pointer to target only the image and the heading text?" --> Right! In chrome it's working fine (I updated this in my question) but with Firefox it does not work.

Comment: yeah im using chrome its working i opened it whi firefox the second not hovering

Comment: @dash on mac firefox its working fine.

Comment: @dash see [button element in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#wikiArticle) - *"Permitted content [Phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content) but there must be no [Interactive content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Interactive_content)"*... that means *user interactions* inside button can be disallowed - Chrome is *lenient* here Firefox *enforces* it... simple - don't use such *markup*!

Answer (score 0):

This was a six years old Firefox bug which was fixed in Firefox 66.

Children of the `button` tag now do respond to `:hover`. :)